# Implementing Progress Bar for a client server case

Tags: rest, vue.js, progress-bar

I have following case, I have a client implemented in vue.js and a python base backend using flask framework.

I have a restful interface where from client I need to send a request to server to start certain operations. This operation may take long time 4-5 minutes and I know to show the progress. How this can be implemented between client and server with current technology stack for a http REST interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are buncha of "loading" components for Vue (as Nuxt has their own `$loading`), i will just use an example `b-spinner` of BootstrapVue and `Axios` as HTTP Client:

`<b-spinner ng-if="loadingProgress">` (shows Spinner if loadingProgress/sending request until server return response)

```
methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      //set loading progess as true
      this.loadingProgress = true;
      axios.post(
        '[your_API_URL]',
        {
          // data you wanted to POST as JSON
        },
      ).then((response) => {
        // reset your component inputs like textInput to null
        // or your custom route redirect with vue-router
      }).catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          alert(error.response.data); // the error response
        }
      });
    },
```

Further example of my contact form using BSpinner + AJAX Axios POST on Formspree.io [here](https://github.com/SayChunKim/portfolio-vue-spa/blob/master/src/pages/ContactPage.vue)

Another is `vue-wait` component (link [here](https://github.com/f/vue-wait))

Hope those're what you're seeking.